# Pandas column string method on row functions

Tags: python, string, pandas

I am trying to calculate a new column based on conditions of three other columns using string methods.

Sample data:

```
d = pd.DataFrame({'street1': ['1000 foo dr', '1001 bar dr', '1002 foo dr suite101', '1003 bar dr'], 
              'street2': ['city_a', np.nan, 'suite 101', 'suite 102'], 
              'city': ['city_a', 'city_b', np.nan, 'city_c']})

street1                 street2     city
1000 foo dr             city_a      city_a
1001 bar dr             NaN         city_b
1002 foo dr suite101    suite 101   NaN
1003 bar dr             suite 102   city_c
```

ideal output:

```
Address
1000 foo dr
1001 bar dr
1002 foo dr suite 101
1003 bar dr suite 102
```

The idea here is

- if `street2` matches `city`, ignore
- if `street2` matches the end of `street1`, ignore
- otherwise, concatenate `street1` and `street2`

What I tried:

```
def address_clean(row):
    if not row['street2']:
        return row['street1']
    if row['street2'] == row['city']:
        return row['street1']
    elif row['street1'].str.replace(' ', '').find(row['street2'].str.replace(' ', '')) != -1:
        return row['street1']
    else:
        return row['street1'] + row['street2']

d.apply(lambda row: address_clean(row), axis=1).head()
```

This one throws me an error:

```
AttributeError: ("'str' object has no attribute 'str'", 'occurred at index 1')
```

It seems like the `row[street1]` is a `string` instead of a `pd.Series`. However even if I remove the `.str` part from the original function, which became:

```
def address_clean(row):
    if not row['street2']:
        return row['street1']
    if row['street2'] == row['city']:
        return row['street1']
    elif row['street1'].replace(' ', '').find(row['street2'].replace(' ', '')) != -1:
        return row['street1']
    else:
        return row['street1'] + row['street2']

d.apply(lambda row: address_clean(row), axis=1).head()
```

The code throws me the following error:

```
AttributeError: ("'float' object has no attribute 'replace'", 'occurred at index 1')
```

I am wondering which part of the function was I using incorrectly, and how to solve this error.

Comment: Your second error could be due to having NaN values, `type(np.nan)` gives `float`

Comment: You expected output is weird. Where did `suite 123` come from? And why was row 3 concatenated with row 4?

Comment: @G.Anderson What I don't understand is, if the problem is having NaN values, wouldn't the `if not row['street2']:  return row['street1']` part of the function handle that properly? Why would it be evaluated in the following if statements?

Comment: @Erfan Sorry, was an idiot. I edited the question and made the changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to search a pattern in a series, but I had to use `apply` to find whether a columns ends with the content of another columns. BTW I had to slightly change your data, because `'...suite101'` does not end with `'suite 101'` except if spaces are to be ignored. So I used:

```
d = pd.DataFrame({'street1': ['1000 foo dr', '1001 bar dr', '1002 foo dr suite 101', '1003 bar dr'],
                  'street2': ['city_a', np.nan, 'suite 101', 'suite 102'],
                  'city': ['city_a', 'city_b', np.nan, 'city_c']})

print(pd.DataFrame({'Address': np.where(d.street2.str.contains('city', na=True)
               | d.apply(lambda x: x.street1.endswith(str(x.street2)), axis = 1),
               d.street1,
               d.street1.str.cat(d.street2, sep=' '))}))
```

gives as expected:

```
                 Address
0            1000 foo dr
1            1001 bar dr
2  1002 foo dr suite 101
3  1003 bar dr suite 102
```